# Como saber si una descarga de un archivo se ha producido con Selenium webdriver en python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

estoy realizando un test que descarga un archivo. Esto ya se produce, pero mi pregunta es que si existe alguna forma de verificar que la descarga se ha producido correctamente.

Saludos

Comment: Depende de qué entiendas por "correctamente". Si sólo quieres ver que el fichero ha aparecido, la respuesta de @jbarrio es adecuada. Si quieres verificar que además el fichero está completo y correcto, necesitarías que el servidor te proporcionara también información extra, como su hash md5 o sha1 por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Con comandos basicos de Python puedes comprobar el contenido de un directorio. Por ejemplo:

```
contenido = os.listdir("mi_path")
"nombre_archivo_descargado" in contenido
```

La ultima linea devuelve un boolean y puedes usar un Asset para asegurar el funcionamiento automatico.

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos por la ayuda. Comprobare